# What is the IEC standard number for this plug?

Tags: power-supply, mains, plug

I need the specific IEC standard number for a power plug/socket used in a laptop. See the photo below. I need to know the laptop-side plug (the lower plug in the photo). Thanks. This plug is used in Lenovo laptop power supplies, and others.

[image: image of plugs for Lenovo notebook power supply cable]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lower connector looks like an [IEC 60320 C5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5.2FC6_coupler) to me.